# c# implementation get range of values and union of these ranges

Tags: c#, collections, union, range

I have a situation that is well explained in this question:

[Range intersection / union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208110/range-intersection-union)

I need a C# implementation (a collection maybe) that takes a list of ranges (of ints) and do the union of them.
Then I need to iterate through all ints in this collection (also numbers between ranges)
Are there any library/implementation so that I don't have to rewrite everything by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing that comes to my mind is to use Enumerable.Range, and then treat the different IEnumerable with standard linq operators. Something like:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
.Concat(Enumerable.Range(7, 11))
.Concat(Enumerable.Range(13, 22))

foreach(var number in list)
  // Do something
```

Obviously you can use Union and Intersect as well... clearly you can also put your ranges in a `List<IEnumerable<int>>` or something similar and then iterate over the elements for producing a single list of the elements:

```
var ranges = new List<IEnumerable<int>> 
{ 
    Enumerable.Range(1, 5), 
    Enumerable.Range(7, 11), 
    Enumerable.Range(10, 22) 
};
var unionOfRanges = Enumerable.Empty<int>();

foreach(var range in ranges)
    unionOfRanges = unionOfRanges.Union(range);

foreach(var item in unionOfRanges)
    // Do something
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I prefer your answer or the other one!

Comment: I prefer this answer in the end because is faster to write

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at [this implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/buildingrange.aspx) and see if it will fit your needs.

Combine ranges with `Range.Coalesce`:

```
var range1 = Range.Create(0, 5, "Range 1");
var range2 = Range.Create(11, 41, "Range 2");
var range3 = Range.Create(34, 50, "Range 3");
var ranges = new List<Range> { range1, range2, range3 };
var unioned = Range.Coalesce(ranges);
```

Iterate over ranges with `.Iterate`:

```
foreach (var range in unioned)
{
    foreach (int i in range.Iterate(x => x + 1))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: More specifically, I think the most useful function there would be `Coalesce()`.

Comment: Maybe your answer is the most complete, I like it a lot

Answer (score 1):

The following is vanilla Linq implementation:

```
var r1 = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
var r2 = Enumerable.Range(20,5);
var r3 = Enumerable.Range(-5,10);

var union = r1.Union(r2).Union(r3).Distinct();

foreach(var n in union.OrderBy(n=>n))
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Comment: And also very inefficient for large ranges.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) has just the thing:

- `UnionWith( IEnumerable<T> other )`. Modifies the current HashSet object to contain all elements that are present in itself, the specified collection, or both.
- `IntersectWith( IEnumerable<T> other )`. Modifies the current HashSet object to contain only elements that are present in that object and in the specified collection.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are looking for is called an "interval tree".

You can find different implementations on the net.

For example here's one: http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/RangeSearchTree.aspx